# How to pass a variable in a Golang callback function?

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
func loopThroughDirs(path string, fileInfo os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    ...do something with service...
    return nil
}

func main() {
    service, err := storage.New(client)
    ...
    filepath.Walk(*dirName, loopThroughDirs)
}
```

The problem I want to solve is this, I want to use `service` *inside* `loopThroughDirs()`. How do I do this?

PS:
Is the `loopThroughDirs` function inside `filepath.Walk()` called a callback in Go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also try returning a `WalkFunc`function :

```
func main() {
    service, err := storage.New(client)
    ...
    filepath.Walk(*dirName, getWalkFunc(service))
}

func getWalkFunc(service storage.Service) filepath.WalkFunc {
    return func(path string, fileInfo os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        // ...do something with service...
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. How is this called in Go? I assume 'callback' is wrong :-P

Comment: `getWalkFunc` is basically returning a closure. You can read more about them here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/go/2741/closures/9226/closure-basics

Answer (score 5):

One way is by declaring `loopThroughDirs` anonymously inside `main`:

```
func main() {
    service, err := storage.New(client)
    ...
    filepath.Walk(*dirName, func(path string, fileInfo os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        ...do something with service...
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpful, but for this situation I'm going for the other answer.